# SQL Server next result

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have Stored procedure in sql server. That Stored procedure returns two select (two results). In other StoredProcedure I need to work only with the second result (dataset) and do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 FROM exec MyProcedure
```

but from MyProcedure I need fetch only the second result. Is there any way?

Thanks

Comment: You can not insert stored procedure result into a table directly by executing this. You need to write insert logic inside the procedures.

Comment: *"You can not insert stored procedure result into a table directly by executing this"* Yes you can, @SurajKumar , just remove the `FROM`.

Comment: Possible if you had only one select returning from stored procedure

Comment: @Atk provided the datasets have **same** definition then 2+ datasets is actually fine: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=212c5a1b2a6abfe045df0a41c778d10d). This just seems like a typographical error (`FROM` isn't needed).

Comment: @Larnu Got it I was never seen that before.

Comment: @Larnu Is it possible even in previous versions of SQL server?

Comment: Certainly since 2005, @Atk .

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in the question to answer this. What do the two result sets look like? One sort of solution if they have the same structure. Another sort if they don't.

Comment: This is possible, but only if the second result set has the same structure as the first, and then both will end up in `Table1`. There is no T-SQL construct that will allow you to process the result sets completely separately (except possibly cursors, I've never tested that -- but I doubt you'd want it anyway, given the performance impact). You may want to read [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) for a more comprehensive overview of how stored procedures can (not) share data. In general, don't be afraid to copy code where convenient, or to leave the tough work to client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a column which is returned from the stored proc which you can use as a where statement clause?

If, I do I mean if, the stored procedure always returns data where the 2nd row is the result you want, you could use a rownumber():
[Row Number info from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Then add in the where clause. Where the rownumber = 2. Again this will only work if the data is always returned where the 2nd Row is the row you want.